# Magento 1.9.1.0 Full Text Search Not showing Exact Result

Tags: magento-1.9, category, catalogsearch

I am Using Magento 1.9.1.0 and  i a haven't search the proper searched Product.
if in enter **Windows 7** the result contains **Windows** as well as **7**
so the result Comes **Windows 10** **Windows 8** and all. How i Can Get the Exact Result.

I already Tried Below One:-

```
if ($like) {
                    $likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';
                }
```

in function prepareResult() in FullText.php **But No clue. having same result**

Update:-1 whole Function

```
public function prepareResult($object, $queryText, $query)
    {
        $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
        if (!$query->getIsProcessed()) {
            $searchType = $object->getSearchType($query->getStoreId());

            $preparedTerms = Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')
                ->prepareTerms($queryText, $query->getMaxQueryWords());

            $bind = array();
            $like = array();
            $likeCond  = '';
            if ($searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_LIKE
                || $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE
            ) {
                $helper = Mage::getResourceHelper('core');
                $words = Mage::helper('core/string')->splitWords($queryText, true, $query->getMaxQueryWords());
                foreach ($words as $word) {
                    $like[] = $helper->getCILike('s.data_index', $word, array('position' => 'any'));
                }
                if ($like) {
                    $likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';
                }
            }
            $mainTableAlias = 's';
            $fields = array(
                'query_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr($query->getId()),
                'product_id',
            );
            $select = $adapter->select()
                ->from(array($mainTableAlias => $this->getMainTable()), $fields)
                ->joinInner(array('e' => $this->getTable('catalog/product')),
                    'e.entity_id = s.product_id',
                    array())
                ->where($mainTableAlias.'.store_id = ?', (int)$query->getStoreId());

            if ($searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_FULLTEXT
                || $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE
            ) {
                $bind[':query'] = implode(' ', $preparedTerms[0]);
                $where = Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')
                    ->chooseFulltext($this->getMainTable(), $mainTableAlias, $select);
            }

            if ($likeCond != '' && $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE) {
                    $where .= ($where ? ' AND ' : '') . $likeCond;
            } elseif ($likeCond != '' && $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_LIKE) {
                $select->columns(array('relevance'  => new Zend_Db_Expr(0)));
                $where = $likeCond;
            }

            if ($where != '') {
                $select->where($where);
            }

            $sql = $adapter->insertFromSelect($select,
                $this->getTable('catalogsearch/result'),
                array(),
                Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INSERT_ON_DUPLICATE);
            $adapter->query($sql, $bind);

            $query->setIsProcessed(1);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: provide more detail code

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I have Update the function please help me